# Dygraphs in R with numeric x axis

Tags: r, dygraphs

My question is with reference to this issue [here](https://github.com/rstudio/dygraphs/issues/40).Seeing that dygraph now supports numeric x axis I tried to test a data with numeric x axis however it gave an error. The code that I used is

```
 dygraph(as.data.frame(x = 1:10, y = runif(10))) %>%
  dyAxis("y", valueRange = c(0, 1.5)) %>%
  dyEvent(2, label = "test") %>%
  dyAnnotation(5, text = "A")

Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Comment: it works for me but I have an empty graph!

Comment: Can you please test with any data set with numeric x axis and let me know if it works?

Comment: I just ran your example (with numeric x) and I get the graph but it's empty; maybe there is still an issue.

Comment: I retried with your solution but the error still persists

Comment: try reinstalling the git_hub version devtools::install_github(c("ramnathv/htmlwidgets", "rstudio/dygraphs"))

Comment: Yes. Finally it worked. Thank s a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you were very close; replace as.data.frame with data.frame

```
 dygraph(data.frame(x = 1:10, y = runif(10))) %>%
  dyAxis("y", valueRange = c(0, 1.5)) %>%
  dyEvent(2, label = "test") %>%
  dyAnnotation(5, text = "A")
```